# Mapping every key into a modifier when pressed with another

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, remapping

It has become common to e.g. map Caps Lock to Ctrl as a modifier / Esc when pressed alone. I had an idea to do a similar thing with regular keys, e.g. j+w -> Ctrl+w, but j when pressed alone. I cannot find any resources on that though and I can see some potential problems, e.g. when typing fast one could trigger unwanted mappings. The solution to this particular problem could be using only uncommon sequences (e.g. j+w seems OK, but not j+a). Has anyone tried such a setup and/or can comment of its viability?

Comment: Please edit your question and mention your OS. Under Linux and X, you can use XKB and [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) to implement something like this. As to viability, I think it depends on your personal taste... I couldn't work with something like this, but that's just me.

Comment: It's OS agnostic, I'm just looking for experience with this approach, since I know I had problems when I tried to do similar thing with Space. I could do this myself, but I don't want to commit hours to developing a custom keymap just to find out that it's not going to work out.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something like that and eventually commented it out but I hadn't thought of a good way to have the key work normally when pressed alone(as in you immediately get j when you press j instead of when you release the key or such but somehow get no j if you press w too). But **if you have some use case where getting the regular key's input in addition to your mapping isn't an issue I'd say it's viable**.

I suppose you could also do something like have pressing a mapping try to remove the initial input before executing but that seems kind of troublesome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the world of programmable mechanical keyboards there is a feature known as [homerow mods](https://precondition.github.io/home-row-mods) that provides functionality similar to what you describe. Homerow mods work very well once you have adjusted to them, but the adjustment period can be challenging and many people give up before getting there.

One recipe for success is to carefully adjust the timings of multiple aspects of the behavior of the homerow mods keys, which can be difficult to do at a higher layer of abstraction like AutoHotkey. Some important considerations include things like: how long do you have to hold a key before its modifier behavior is activated, how long must you pause prior to holding a key in order to activate its modifier behavior, and does a held key only act as a modifer if another key is pressed and released while it is continuously held. But there are quite a few other subtle factors that can be tweaked as well.

Keyboard firmware like QMK and ZMK gives you all of the necessary settings, granularity, and tolerances for dialing in what best works for you, so I would strongly recommend looking into building, buying, or borrowing a programmable keyboard if you want to explore this idea further.